# nginx + HTTP/2 + HTTP POST + Safari = Error

Tags: nginx, https, safari, mobile-safari, http2

After updating to nginx 1.10.0 + OpenSSL 1.0.2 (to take advantage of ALPN negotiation) an interesting issue has surfaced in Safari (v9, mobile and desktop) where the **first** HTTP POST request to the server fails. No request ever hits the server.

Safari returns this message in the Console: `Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server.`.

Subsequent POST requests (click the same button again) succeed.

**nginx build details**

`nginx version: nginx/1.10.0
built by gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --user=nginx --group=nginx --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-file-aio --with-http_realip_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-openssl=/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2d`

**nginx config**

```
user  nginx;    
worker_processes  1;    

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;    
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;    

events {    
    use epoll;    
    worker_connections  1024;    
    multi_accept on;    
}    


http {    
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;    
    default_type  application/octet-stream;    

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;    

    sendfile        on;    

    proxy_buffer_size   256k;    
    proxy_buffers   4 512k;    
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   512k;    

    server_tokens off;    
    client_max_body_size 1G;    

    keepalive_disable safari msie6;    
    keepalive_timeout 0;    

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;    
}    

server {    
    listen       443 ssl http2;    
    server_name  *.gingrapp.com;    

    root /var/www/html;    

    ssl on;    
    ssl_certificate ***.crt;    
    ssl_certificate_key ***.crt;    
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dhparams.pem;    
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;    
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';    
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;    
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;    
    ssl_session_timeout 2m;    

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=420420420420;";    

    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;    

    gzip on;    
    gzip_static on;    
    gzip_proxied any;    
    gzip_types application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript application/xml text/css text/javascript         text/plain text/x-component text/xml;    
    gzip_min_length 10240;    
    gzip_buffers 16 128k;    

    open_file_cache max=2000 inactive=60s;    
    open_file_cache_valid 90s;    
    open_file_cache_min_uses 5;    
    open_file_cache_errors off;    

    keepalive_disable safari msie6;    
    keepalive_timeout 0;    

    location /assets {    
        etag on;    
        access_log        off;    

        keepalive_disable safari msie6;    
        keepalive_timeout 0;    
    }    

    location / {    
        index  index.php  index.html index.htm;    
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;    
    }    

    error_page  404              /404.html;    
    location = /404.html {    
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;    
    }    

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;    
    location = /50x.html {    
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;    
    }    

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {    
        include fastcgi_params;    
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;    

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;    
        fastcgi_index index.php;    
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 512m;    
        fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;    
        fastcgi_buffers 4 512k;    
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 512k;    

        gzip on;    
        gzip_static on;    
        gzip_proxied any;    
        gzip_types application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript application/xml text/css text/javascript         text/plain text/x-component text/xml;    
        gzip_min_length 10240;    
        gzip_buffers 16 128k;    

        keepalive_disable safari msie6;    
        keepalive_timeout 0;    
    }    
}
```

Comment: I tried updating to OpenSSL 1.0.2h as well. No change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug in nginx 1.9.15 and 1.10.0

-https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/979

-https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/959

I "solved" this issue by downgrading to nginx 1.9.12 + OpenSSL 1.0.2h.